# VSTO - MS Office 'Color Scheme' changed event

Tags: vsto

Using VSTO, how can I get notification of changes to the MS Office color scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully something better exists with Office 2010. Here's what I used for Office 2007 and Word (This is not a notification in any way, just something to check for):

```
const string OfficeCommonKey =
  @"Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common";
const string OfficeThemeValueName = "Theme";
const int ThemeBlue = 1;
const int ThemeSilver = 2;
const int ThemeBlack = 3;

using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(OfficeCommonKey, false))
{
    int theme = (int)key.GetValue(OfficeThemeValueName,1);

    switch (theme)
    {
        case ThemeBlue:
            //...
            break;
        case ThemeSilver:
            //...
            break;
        case ThemeBlack:
            //...
            break;
        default:
            //...
            break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that (of course) this has been changed in Office 2013. The following constants should be used instead:

```cs
const string OfficeCommonKey =
  @"Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common";
const string OfficeThemeValueName = "UI Theme";
const int ThemeWhite = 0;
const int ThemeLightGray = 1;
const int ThemeDarkGray = 2;
```

Note that if the theme has never been set, the "UI Theme" key won't exist. I believe it defaults to "0" (White theme), though.

Comment: for me in office 365 2016 its: color=1, grey=3, dark=4, white=5

Answer (score 1):

I have code similar to what Mike Regan has provided. One extra thing I do is run a seperate thread which keeps checking this registry entry every second. Whenever, the registry value changes, I trigger a custom event.
The rest of the code in my add-in handles the event and changes the UI elements corresponding to the new theme in this event handler.