# Get correct text color on custom task pane

Tags: ms-office, vsto, excel-addins

I am currently building a Excel addin with a custom task pane.
The background color respects the selected theme, i.e. it is Dark Gray when that Office theme has been selected.
However, the text of labels is not. It is still black even with the Dark Gray theme, meaning it is barely readable.

Is there a way to get the correct text color from Office based on the selected theme? If not, how else would you fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTO - MS Office 'Color Scheme' changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631461/vsto-ms-office-color-scheme-changed-event)

Comment: Also see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd3ff337-1c80-49ff-be2e-b143462bc97b/how-do-you-get-the-current-outlook-2007-color-theme?forum=vsto wherein someone says the exact colors are not available, that he used a color picker to figure out each individual color. Not exactly convenient.