# Is it possible to get the current Office-Design via C# in VSTO-Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing a Outlook VSTO-Add-In and I'm wondering if I can get the current Office-Design (Black, DarkGrey, White, Colorful) using C#, so I can change the Theme of my Window depending on which Theme in Outlook ist active.

Does anyone know if and how I can do this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631461/vsto-ms-office-color-scheme-changed-event This may help. Explains how to get the theme based on a registry key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Comment of Danny Goodall was right!

Note: "OfficeThemeValueName" = "UI Theme" and not "Theme"
      change the version in "OfficeCommonKey" to your used Version of Office

Theme White is Number 5
Theme Black is Number 4
Theme DarkGrey is Number 3
Theme Color is Number 0